# Can there be black holes in a 1+1D spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature

In 2D Einstein tensor is always zero, that means no mass (or cosmological constant or other stress energy tensor component) is allowed. Nevertheless, we can get nonzero Riemann, even nonzero Ricci tensor. Also, we can consider the $M$ in Schwarzchild metric just a constant - not actual mass - it will still remain a valid EFE solution. So, can there be black holes in 2D (or 1+1D) universe?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604208/2451

Comment: Here is an interesting 1+1 black hole example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737828/